# How to have multiple values for single step in QDoubleSpinBox

Tags: qt, qt5

I am using QT QDouleSpinBox with single Step value of 1.0

When i change the value it changes by 1 each increment.

When i hold Control key and change the value than each increment is by 10.0

Now i want to add Alt key and change the each increment by 0.1 , how can i do that ?

I am trying to promote the QDoubleSpinBox widget in the QT designer with this class.

how to implement the stepBy function ?

```
#pragma once
#include< QDoubleSpinBox>

class spinboxsumit : public  QDoubleSpinBox
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    spinboxsumit(QWidget * parent = 0);
    void stepBy(double steps);

};

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

#include "spinboxsumit.h"
spinboxsumit::spinboxsumit(QWidget * parent) : QDoubleSpinBox( parent)
{

}


void spinboxsumit::stepBy(double steps)
{


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Good question. Given the number of available modifier keys, something more flexible would be nice! There's nothing "built-in" for this. I see you're trying to re-implement a custom version... that's was my thought as well.

Here's the (almost) simplest version I could come up with.  BTW `ALT` modifier doesn't work for me (Win7) and the mouse wheel for some reason (no adjustment at all, even with a "stock" spin box), so I used `SHIFT` here as modifier for the test. (Don't know why Alt+wheel doesn't work, could just be my system.)

```cpp
#include <QDoubleSpinBox>
#include <QApplication>

class DoubleBox : public QDoubleSpinBox
{
  Q_OBJECT
  public:
    using QDoubleSpinBox::QDoubleSpinBox;  // inherit c'tors

    // re-implement to keep track of default step (optional, could hard-code step in stepBy())
    void setSingleStep(double val)
    {
      m_defaultStep = val;
      QDoubleSpinBox::setSingleStep(val);
    }

    // override to adjust step size
    void stepBy(int steps) override
    {
      // set the actual step size here
      double newStep = m_defaultStep;
      if (QApplication::queryKeyboardModifiers() & Qt::ShiftModifier)
        newStep *= 0.1;
      // be sure to call the base setSingleStep() here to not change m_defaultStep.
      QDoubleSpinBox::setSingleStep(newStep);
      QDoubleSpinBox::stepBy(steps);
    }

  private:
    double m_defaultStep = 1.0;
};
```

And a quick test:

```cpp
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  QApplication a(argc, argv);
  QDialog d;
  d.setLayout(new QVBoxLayout);
  d.layout()->addWidget(new DoubleBox(&d));
  return d.exec();
}
#include "main.moc"
```

Do go further, one could re-implement a more complete version of `stepBy(int)` ([current source](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp.html#_ZN16QAbstractSpinBox6stepByEi)), or at a lower level by re-implementing [wheel](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp.html#_ZN16QAbstractSpinBox10wheelEventEP11QWheelEvent)/[key](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractspinbox.cpp.html#1018) events.